# Angularjs reloading route in a new tab and update same

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I have following code that reloads the page based on route

```
$location.path('/chartpage');
$route.reload();
```

It works fine but I want to do further two things

1. Load the page in new tab or browser window
2. Anytim I reload the page again it reloads the same browser.

Idea is that on my current page as the numbers are changed I want this other browser to reload to show the chart wit changed values. 
Thanks

Comment: Angular is a Single Page Application framework (SPA).  if you load a page in a new window, it's no longer part of the same Single Page Application.

Comment: Its okay because in new window it updates data from database doesn't depend current page. But when current page values are changed I want to just trigger to refresh that page

Comment: right, so how would you expect the angular app on the first tab to know about and know when to update the second angular app on the other tab?

Comment: on the page when the information is changed using $watch call the controller or use same controller for that page as well with two binding update the portion with $scope.

Comment: You miss the point entirely.  This is not how angular is designed.  You **caanot** communicate between two browser windows with angular in this way.  If two pages is your only option, you will need a non)angular solution.